# Trying to locate a button in an html table by the inner text of a cell in the same row

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am writing codedUI tests in C# and I need to locate a button that is in a row based off of what is contained another cell.

The structure of the table is:

```
<div class="requestGrid k-grid k-widget" id="currentRequestArea" data-bind="visible: workGridVisible, kendoGrid: gridOptions" data-role="grid"><table role="grid"><tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-rowid': workItemID }, css: { 'k-state-selected': workItemID() === $parent.currentWorkItemID() }, template: 'colTmpl'" data-rowid="2237852">    
<td>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <div style="width: 90px;">
            <div title="Start Examination" style="float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bind="attr: { title: actions.examineMessage }" data-html="true" data-placement="top">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bind="clickDisableEnable: $parent.startExamination, enable: actions.canExamine"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td data-bind="click: $parent.openRequest">
    <span data-bind="text: requestNumber">D80103E</span>
</td>
```

I need to locate the div titled "Start Examination" based on the text in the cell with the data-bind of requestNumber.

I have been able to locate the span containing the Request Number with this bit of code

```
        public HtmlSpan Request(string RRNumber)
    {
        if ((this.mRequest == null))
        {                
            this.mRequest = new HtmlSpan(this);
            this.mRequest.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, "data-bind=\"text: requestNumber\"", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
            this.mRequest.SearchProperties[HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.InnerText] = RRNumber; 
        }

        return this.mRequest;

    }

    private HtmlSpan mRequest;
```

My next problem is trying to traverse up to the button that is in a sibling cell. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using HtmlAgilityPack (you can install it using Nuget).
after you have loaded the Html code to `string html`, you can search through it like this:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

// Create the HtmlAgilityPack Document
HtmlDocument Document = new HtmlDocument();
// Fill the Document
Document.LoadHtml(html);
// use the below function to load the Containing Node
HtmlNode StartExNode = getStartExNode(Document);
// Load the Button using the function below
string Button = getButton(StartExNode);

public HtmlNode getStartExNode(HtmlDocument Document)
{
    return Document // return the HtmlNode
        .DocumentNode
        .Descendants("div") // Get all descendants of the type div
        .Where(d =>
            d.Attributes.Contains("title") && // that conatin a title (you need to check to avoid null exceptions from the next query)
            d.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Start Examination") // the title must match "Start Examination" 
        );
}

public string getButton(HtmlNode Node)
{
    return Node // Return button as string
        .Descendants("button") // get all descendants of type button
        .FirstOrDefault() // if there are more, use the first (more check to implement here)
        .OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: That helps with getting the button but the more complex problem is finding the row with the request number, and then finding that button.

Comment: You can not only search for HTML-Children, but also for Parents, if you are using HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Again I don't think this will help me seeing as when working with CodedUI tests you need HTML Elements.